# Vim not sourcing files on startup

Tags: vimrc, invocation

I am root on the machine, and have my .vimrc at `/root/.vimrc`.  Vim ignores this, even though

```
# echo $HOME
/root
```

If I do

```
# vim -u /root/.vimrc some-file-to-edit
```

vim still ignores it.  Setting `export MYVIMRC=root/.vimrc` has no effect.

Vim sources my file without problems if I start vim and type `:source /root/.vimrc`.

Note `VIMINIT` is unset.

**What could be preventing vim from sourcing my .vimrc when starting up?**

I'm happy to supply any other information that may be helpful, just let me know what.

---

**EDIT 1: excerpt from running `vim -V filename`:**

```
...
finished sourcing $VIM/vimrc
chdir(/root)
fchdir() to previous dir 
sourcing "$HOME/.vimrc"
Searching for "filetype.vim" in "/root/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/root/.vim/after"
Searching for "/root/.vim/filetype.vim"
...
```

The full output is long, so this is just an excerpt to show the line that verifies sourcing of `/root/.vimrc`.

---

**EDIT 2: output from running `:scriptnames` after vim normally***

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  7: ~/.vimrc
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/python.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim
```

Again, seems to be sourcing `/root/.vimrc` (item 7).  Soo... line 8 makes me suspicious: my problem is that the indent settings in my vimrc aren't reflected.  Maybe they are being superceeded...

---

**EDIT 3: Placing my file in `~/.vim/after/...`**

Moving my file to the following locations had no effect on the output of `scriptnames`:

- `~/.vim/after/indent.vim`
- `~/.vim/after/indent.vim/myscript.vim`
- `~/.vim/after/indent/myscript.vim`
- `~/.vim/after/syntax/myscript.vim`
- `~/.vim/after/indent/myscript.vim`
- `~/.vim/after/myscript.vim`

And, while moving my to

- `~/.vim/after/plugin/.vimrc`

did change the output of `:scriptnames`, causing my file to be sourced after item 20 (see above), it seems my indent settings are still getting overridden (probably by item 21).

Use of the `after` directory doesn't work how I imagined (see my list of attempts).  Only `after/plugins/` seems to be considered.

Is there a way to ensure that the file is sourced after everything?

Comment: What's the output of `:scriptnames` when you run `vim` normally?

Comment: "I am the root on the machine" -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HG2w0_WyOU

Comment: @muru thanks for the comment -- see **EDIT2**

Comment: You probably need to use a `~/.vim/after/indent.vim` or `~/.vim/after/indent/foo.vim` if you want to override those.

Comment: Thanks again @muru.  Some progress, but vim doesn't seem to take `~/.vim/after/indent/foo.vim` into consideration.  I experimented with different locations under `~/.vim/after/...`, but for the most part, files therein are ignored see **EDIT 3**

Comment: @EdwardNewell Foo in that case was supposed to be the filetype (not an arbitrary string), so try `python.vim` if you're looking to override python indent settings.

Comment: Ok I get it.  I had to move it to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`, because it turns out that my indent settings were being overridden in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim`  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

First opening vim normally and doing `:scriptnames` showed that, in fact, my `~/.vimrc` *was* sourced.  Other scripts were just overridding my indent settings.

Moving just the lines pertaining to indentation from my `~/.vimrc` into a new file at `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` solved the problem.  The filename is crucial, and it is only executed when reading python files.

Alternatively put the file in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python/some-name.vim`.

Comment: Both your and [Alexander Batischev](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/7415/alexander-batischev) answers helped.  I noticed that `vim` was searching `/root/.vim/` which woke me up to the fact I was launching via `sudo`. To get my settings loaded, `sudo -E vim ...`  to use my environment.

Answer (score 7):

You can see what Vim does on startup with `vim -V`. Does it touch the file? Is there any errors?

Safe for errors, my only guess is that filename contains non-ASCII character that looks like "c"; you might not notice it if you always autocomplete the name of the file instead of typing it out in its entirety.